# Getting rid of While Loops in function(s)

Tags: sql-server, cte, reporting

I am running into a problem where WHILE loops are crushing performance under higher data volumes just simply because of the number of iterations through the loop it is taking to get to the final result.

I am looking at a Recursive CTE, but I am running into not really knowing how to pass a variable that gets tallied at the end of an iteration that subsequently gets passed back into a function. Here is the code

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Erlang_C_Required]
(
  -- Add the parameters for the function here
  @NCO FLOAT -- Average Arrival Rate  (second)
  ,
  @AHT FLOAT -- Average Call Duration (seconds)
  ,
  @TASA FLOAT -- Time Goal
  ,
  @TSVL FLOAT -- Service Level Goal
)
 RETURNS @Return TABLE ( Agents FLOAT NOT NULL )
AS
BEGIN
    IF @NCO = 0.0
        BEGIN
            INSERT  INTO @Return
                    SELECT  0;
            RETURN;
        END;
    IF @AHT = 0.0
        BEGIN
            INSERT  INTO @Return
                    SELECT  0;
            RETURN;
        END;
    IF @TASA = 0.0
        BEGIN
            SET @TASA = 30.0;
        END;
    IF @TSVL = 0.0
        BEGIN
            SET @TSVL = .7;
        END;
    DECLARE @Traffic FLOAT; -- Traffic Intensity
    SET @Traffic = ( @NCO / 1800 ) * @AHT;

    DECLARE @Agents FLOAT; --number of agents

    SET @Agents = 2;

    WHILE ( SELECT  Serv
            FROM    dbo.Erlang_C_Serv(@Agents, @Traffic, @TASA, @AHT)
          ) <= @TSVL
        BEGIN
            SET @Agents = @Agents + 1;
        END;


-- Return the result of the function

    INSERT  INTO @Return
            SELECT  @Agents;
    RETURN;

END;
```

So the question is how would I go about eliminating the WHILE loop (there are more nested in this "tree" of functions that get called for this Erlang C calculation)

Comment: It's not the `WHILE` crushing performance specifically (well, it is, but it's not the big problem here), it's the function. You will have to investigate pulling that `dbo.Erlang_C_Serv` functionality into this query directly instead of calling into it.

Comment: There are couple of other functions that are nested as well further "down" the function rabbit hole. Its almost like Function Inception. My follow up question would be should I get them all into the same query?

Comment: Yes, you should write set based queries not iterative code. (If the algorithm is inherently not possible to convert to a SQL set based method then you might look at doing it in CLR instead rather than nested scalar UDFs)